# javascript function not work in php properly

Tags: javascript, php, alert, message

This is my `php` code. after insert data, I am used alert message. Message appeared properly. but it not close when I click **`x`** cross sign.

```
if(isset($_POST['create_post'])){

    $name =  $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $msg = $_POST['description'];



    $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO message(name,email,country,msg,date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,now())");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $name,$email,$country,$msg);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->close();

    if($stmt){

        echo '<div class= "alert">';
        echo '  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display="none";">&times;</span> ';
        echo 'Your messaage has been sent ';
        echo '    </div>';

    }else{
        die('Query fialed' . mysqli_error($connection));
    }

}
```

Alert message part:

```
echo '<div class= "alert">';
echo '  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display="none";">&times;</span> ';
echo 'Your messaage has been sent ';
echo '    </div>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line has too many nested `"` marks:

`echo '  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display="none";">&times;</span> ';`

If you escape the inner ones properly  (`\"`) it will work.

Fiddle example by using raw HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/myingling/3vv7jLd4/

Better yet, I'd just remove the `echo` statements, so it looks like this:

```
if($stmt){
 ?>

    <div class= "alert">
      <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
      Your messaage has been sent 
    </div>
 <?php
 }else{
```

Comment: can you edit y code properly, because your answer's code make an error for me :(

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'none' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\

Comment: if you can please edit my code properly,thank you very much

Comment: Updated.  Just forgot to remove one of the `';` for the closing `</div>`

Comment: Thank you very much :D its working fine now :) and I have a question. why use php tags like this  **?>  <?php**

Comment: I would say to close previous block of php code and open a new one. Keep in mind that <div> element is simply html, no need to "echo" it from php.

Comment: HietuHT is correct.  It "turns off" your PHP code for a few lines of "raw" client-side code.  You can read more about them here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php   (In newer versions of php you can make the opening tag just `<?` instead of `<?php`, but I've got an old (backwards-compatible) habbit of using the full tag.)

Comment: @HieuHT  Thank you very much